# Why useContext does't work in my function?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to build a todo list app and I'm stuck with this problem. I'm very interested to see how i can fix this error.

I have rearrange all my funciton to class component but that don't fix my error.

List.js

```
import React, { createContext } from 'react';

export let ListContext = createContext();

export const Data = [
    {
        name: 'Joe',
        age: 19
    },
    {
        name: 'John',
        age: 16
    },
    {
        name: 'Claire',
        age: 17
    },
    {
        name: 'Alex',
        age: 16
    }
]

export default class List extends React.Component {

    list = () => {
        let list = Data.map(Data => <li key={Data.age}>{Data.name}</li>)
        return (
            <div>{list}</div>
        )
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>

                {this.list()}
            </div>
        )

    }
}
```

TodoForm.js

```
export default function Todo() {
    let inputValue = {
        value: ''
    }
    function handleChange(e) {
        inputValue.value = e.target.value;
    }
    function handleClick() {
        const value = useContext(ListContext);
    }
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div>
                <input type="text" onChange={handleChange} className="inp" />
                <button onClick={handleClick} className="btn" >Add New</button>

            </div>

        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

The useContext return this error: ./src/TodoForm.js
  Line 12:  React Hook "useContext" is called in function "handleClick" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is here,

```
function handleClick() {
   const value = useContext(ListContext);
}
```

from the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html):

> Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions. Instead, always use Hooks at the top level of your React function. By following this rule, you ensure that Hooks are called in the same order each time a component renders. That’s what allows React to correctly preserve the state of Hooks between multiple useState and useEffect calls. (If you’re curious, we’ll explain this in depth below.)

And

> Call Hooks from React function components. Call Hooks from custom Hooks (we’ll learn about them on the next page).

`useContext` is react `Hook` and you cannot call this into regular function. React `Hook` run automatically when page finishes loading.

Comment: thank you but i have another problem can you help me to solve it ?

Comment: @LeartMorina sure.

Comment: do you have any social media because my account doesn't allow me to ask question?